# VS Code: BracketPair Settings: excludedLanguages is not an array

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In VS Code, I keep getting the pop up message:

> BracketPair Settings: excludedLanguages is not an array
> Source: Null Extension Description (Extension)

How do I silent it?
The plugin Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 is not installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restarting my VSCode *after* uninstalling the plugin fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

After uninstalling the plugin, check your settings.json and remove the bracketPair configuration:

```
{
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active"
}
```

Then, restart your VSCode as @MattSlater mentioned.